# Horizontally aligned and vertically centered collage in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to put few images in a canvas, in such a way so that they become horizontally aligned and vertically centered collage in tikz. Below is the sample code-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] (img1) at (0, 0, 0) {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{pc}};
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] (img2) at (img1.south east){\includegraphics[height=1cm]{arrow}};
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] (img3) at (img2.south east){\includegraphics[height=3cm]{db}};
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] (img4) at (img3.south east){\includegraphics[height=1cm]{arrow}};
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] (img5) at (img4.south east){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{pc}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is how the generated pdf looks like-
[image]

However, I want to the arrows vertically centered, something like this-
[image]

Notice the alignment of the images in both the files.

Comment: Try `anchor=west` and `.east` instead of `anchor=south west` and `.south east`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Du you mean `\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] (img3) at (img2.south west){\includegraphics[height=3cm]{db}};` ?

Comment: No, he meant `\node[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (img3) at (img2.east) {\includegraphics{...}};`. What you have done in your code is to place the lower left corner (`anchor=south west`) of the second image  on the lower right corner (`at (img1.south east)`) of the first image, so naturally they're aligned at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `positioning` library. `right = of` horizontally aligns nodes by their center:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
    \node (img1) {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};
    \node[right=0pt of img1] (img2) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}};
    \node[right=0pt of img2] (img3) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}};
    \node[right=0pt of img3] (img4) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}};
    \node[right=0pt of img4] (img5) {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it. I would like to know more about `positioning` library. Can you please tell me other than `right = of`, what are the other parameters available in this library?

Comment: @RaviJoshi See section 17.5.3 *Advanced Placement Options* in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any other graphical elements then you don't need to use TikZ at all. The output of this is the same as Ignasi's code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % provides valign-key for includegraphics
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}% end-of-line percent character removes space between images from line break in code
\includegraphics[height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[height=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I never knew about `valign` parameter.

Comment: @RaviJoshi As mentioned in the comment in the code, you need `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to use that. If you just load `graphicx`, it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution as Torbjørn, but without `adjustbox`, can be achieved using `\raisebox`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{-1.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}%
\raisebox{-0.5cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}%
\raisebox{-1.5cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}%
\raisebox{-0.5cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}%
\raisebox{-1.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I am glad to see that there exists many ways to get the same thing done. Truly helpful.